# How to implement different permission in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model **Payment** with fields: date_created, comment, description, amount. Each payment belongs to User.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=datetime.now())
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Now I need to implement different roles for User: regular (can CRUD his payments), manager (can CRUD users), admin (can CRUD everything). So, the main question is how to implement this roles for users during registration (further it can't be changed). I also need to be able to set this role during registration via api (django rest framework).

Comment: there two questions you should separate it. In a nutshell you could add `CharField` with role choice in user model and then check it via permission class which DRF provided

Comment: there are actually many ways how you can implement it. Basically, you have already described in the question that 1. You need to create permissions, 2. assign this permissions to users, 3. check in views or somewhere else if users have permissions to perform different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to user Django built-in Permissions

```
#e.g.
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='admin_can_manage_users')
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Comment: Mark your answer as "correct" so that this question disappears from "unanswered" section